# При запкске сценария вылазиет ошибка:"expected an indented block" что делать?

Tags: python

Я проверил код несколько раз и не нашёл ошибок отступов (Не могу понять в чём причина). Помогите пожалуйста

```
import os
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process 

Registry = True
MatchingSearch = True
OperationWhile = True
BruteForceMatches= True

print('Registry v0.1')

while Registry:

    print('''   Что вам надо?
        Найти
        Добавить
        Удалить
        Корректировать''')

    while OperationWhile:

        Operation = input

        OperationLikenessFind    = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Найти')
        OperationLikenessAdd     = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Добавить')
        OperationLikenessDelete  = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Удалить')
        OperationLikenessCorrect = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Корректировать')

        if OperationLikenessFind >= 50:

            Storage = open('Storage.txt', 'r')
            StorageList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('Storage.txt')]

            print('Что вы ищите?')

            while MatchingSearch:
                Search = input()
                
            ResultSearchNumber = StorageList.index(Search)
            print(StorageList(int(ResultSearchNumber)))

        if OperationLikenessAdd >= 70:

        if OperationLikenessDelete >= 60:

        if OperationLikenessCorrect >= 80:

        else:
            print('Напиши то, что тебя интересует (Найти, добавить, удалить, корректировать)')

    End = input('Ещё?')
    if End == 'Нет':

        Storage.close

        Registry = False
```

Comment: После ифоф пустые строки

Answer (score 1):

В вашем коде у операторов if нет тела.

Answer (score 1):

Следующие ошибки:

1. Цикл `while MatchingSearch:` никогда не закончится.
2. Цикл `while OperationWhile:` никогда не закончится, поэтому до `End = input('Ещё?')` дело не дойдёт.
3. В `Operation = input` не хватает скобок.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
from fuzzywuzzy import process 

Registry = True
MatchingSearch = True
OperationWhile = True
BruteForceMatches= True

print('Registry v0.1')

while Registry:

    print('''   Что вам надо?
        Найти
        Добавить
        Удалить
        Корректировать''')

    while OperationWhile:

        Operation = input()    # тут нужны скобки ибо программа уходит в бесконечность

        OperationLikenessFind    = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Найти')
        OperationLikenessAdd     = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Добавить')
        OperationLikenessDelete  = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Удалить')
        OperationLikenessCorrect = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(Operation, 'Корректировать')

        if OperationLikenessFind >= 50:

            Storage = open('Storage.txt', 'r')
            StorageList = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('Storage.txt')]

            print('Что вы ищите?')

            while MatchingSearch:
                Search = input()
                
            ResultSearchNumber = StorageList.index(Search)
            print(StorageList(int(ResultSearchNumber)))

        if OperationLikenessAdd >= 70:
            pass                             # если вы пока не хотите ничего делать в этом случае или не придумали подходящее решение
        if OperationLikenessDelete >= 60:
            pass
        if OperationLikenessCorrect >= 80:
            pass
        else:
            print('Напиши то, что тебя интересует (Найти, добавить, удалить, корректировать)')

    End = input('Ещё?')
    if End == 'Нет':

        Storage.close

        Registry = False
```

Answer (score -1):

У вас оператор if стоит так что Питон его интерпретирует как часть while и посему не продолжает исполнение корректно. Выведите if в отдельное тело, тогда код корректно исполниться.Не в отступах дело, а в последовательности чтения Питоном кода.
Отступы можно перевести массово через любой текстовый редактор. В том числе и в IDLE от Python: Edit/Select all и потом пункт Format

Comment: В какое отдельное тело? Куда надо их вывести, чтобы код стал работать? Можете привести готовый код?

Comment: Что вы имеете в виду? Отдельное тело? А как это сделать? Можете показать пожалуйста наглядно